# Unable to display simple forms for user input and password on ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got up and running facebooks, [ReactJS my-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app). I am just trying to understand it better.

I have added some images, p tags, h tags etc in

> app.js

file which has a **render()** function in a class called **app**, it was working fine. But when I was trying to display a simple form with username and password. Its showing a complete blank page.

```
<form>
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>
```

I have seen some blogs walking me through how to get forms running on React.js. But I want to know the reason why reactjs is not displaying them. It would be nice If you suggest how to approach for creating a simple username and password on reactjs. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: can u share the code for form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code needs closing tags:

```
    <form>
      First name:<br/>
      <input type="text" name="firstname"/><br/>
      Last name:<br/>
      <input type="text" name="lastname"/>
    </form>
```